# How do I find the maxima of the function x+y such that x^2+y^2=1?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

It is a simple question. I am trying to maximise x+y for coordinates {x,y} that lies on a circle of radius one. I tried using FindMaximum.

```
FindMaximum[{x + y, x^2 + y^2 = 1}, {x, y}]
```

But I am getting this error.

```
Set::write: Tag Plus in x^2+y^2 is Protected. >>
FindMaximum::eqineq: Constraints in {1} are not all equality or inequality constraints. With the exception of integer domain constraints for linear programming, domain constraints or constraints with Unequal (!=) are not supported. >>
```

What's happening here?

Comment: `FindMaximum[{x + y, x^2 + y^2 == 1}, {x, y}]` or `Maximize[{x + y, x^2 + y^2 == 1}, {x, y}]`

Comment: oh yes.. syntax mistake

Answer (score 2):

`FindMaximum[{x + y, x^2 + y^2 == 1}, {x, y}]`